# how can I invoke Mac OS X shutdown programmatically?

Tags: macos, shutdown

when a user presses the shutdown form the menu which process or file is called in return of this to shutdown the mac os

also the directory path of the process

regards.

Comment: I'm guessing the `shutdown` process is called at some extent, but I'm wondering why you're asking this question in the first place?

Comment: i need to call this process with some other source instead off shutdown menu button

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question to instead ask "how can I invoke Mac OS X shutdown programmatically".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute from the command line, or call `osascript` some other way with these arguments.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to shut down'
```

Apple has a [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1134/_index.html) about programmatically restarting, shutting down, or logout. (Thanks @[NSGod](https://superuser.com/users/56812/nsgod))

Comment: This is like the normal GUI-induced shutdown, e.g. canceling the prompt for unsaved documents will cancel shutdown. According to your question, this is the behavior you want. If not, `shutdown -h now`.

Comment: thanx it is absolutely the thing i required

Comment: Technically, telling the `Finder` to do this is deprecated; you should use `System Events` instead. That said, the end result of either method is basically `kAERestart` being sent to `kSystemProcess` (`loginwindow`).

Comment: @NSGod Well, it's part of the *Legacy Suite*, but I didn't find deprecation mentioned in the ASE *Library*. And it's shorter to type than `System Events`.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo halt` or `sudo reboot` also work. Read `halt(8)`. AFAIK you'll have to be root because the `/sbin/` directory where those programs reside isn't (shouldn't be) in your `PATH` by default.